XML lectura con minidom
La estructura de una parte de un archivo XML es la siguiente:
<Covol:PRODUCTO>
<Covol:ClaveProducto>PR07</Covol:ClaveProducto>
<Covol:ClaveSubProducto>SP16</Covol:ClaveSubProducto>
<Covol:Gasolina>
    <Covol:ComposOctanajeGasolina>87</Covol:ComposOctanajeGasolina>
    <Covol:GasolinaConCombustibleNoFosil>No</Covol:GasolinaConCombustibleNoFosil>
</Covol:Gasolina>
<Covol:MarcaComercial>MAGNA SIN</Covol:MarcaComercial>
<Covol:REPORTEDEVOLUMENMENSUAL>

Al leer esa estructura con el siguiente código de python y minidom, se me genera para la etiqueta "Gasolina" el mensaje de que no tiene un dato asociado; efectivamente, no lo tiene y lo que requiero es la etiqueta y que salte el valor. Estoy validando si ese "nodo" tiene un valor, pero aún así se me sigue presentando el problema. El código es el siguiente.
etiquetas = Producto.getElementsByTagName('*')
for child in etiquetas:
    if child.tagName=="Covol:PRODUCTO":
        continue
    elif child.tagName!="Covol:REPORTEDEVOLUMENMENSUAL":
        print(child.tagName)  
        if (child.firstChild is not None):
            print(child.firstChild.data)
        else:
         print("No tiene contenido")  
    else:
        break

La salida es la siguiente:
Covol:ClaveProducto PR07
Covol:ClaveSubProducto SP16
Covol:Gasolina
'Element' object has no attribute 'data'
De favor alguien de Ustedes me puede apoyar a subsanar el error.

Ten en cuenta que lo que consideras un "nodo sin contenido" es un nodo sin hijos, es decir:
<Covol:Gasolina></Covol:Gasolina>

en cambio,
<Covol:Gasolina>
    <Covol:ComposOctanajeGasolina>87</Covol:ComposOctanajeGasolina>
    <Covol:GasolinaConCombustibleNoFosil>No</Covol:GasolinaConCombustibleNoFosil>
</Covol:Gasolina>

cumplirá el condicional if (child.firstChild is not None): ya que el primer nodo hijo de  <Covol:Gasolina> es <Covol:ComposOctanajeGasolina>.
El problema viene cuando se intenta hacer child.firstChild.data, donde child.firstChild es <Covol:ComposOctanajeGasolina> como se comentaba.
En el DOM todo es un nodo, el texto del nodo en realidad está contenido en un nodo hijo  de tipo Text que es el que tiene los datos en si, <Covol:ComposOctanajeGasolina> no tiene datos en si mismo y es eso lo que causa la excepción:
>>> gasolina = producto.getElementsByTagName('Gasolina')[0]

>>> gasolina.firstChild
<DOM Element: ComposOctanajeGasolina at 0x70ba2c0aff50>

>>> gasolina.firstChild.data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Element' object has no attribute 'data'

>>> gasolina.firstChild.firstChild
<DOM Text node "'87'">

>>> gasolina.firstChild.firstChild.data
'87'

Puedes comprobar el tipo del nodo hijo y solo obtener sus datos cuando sea un nodo Text:
etiquetas = Producto.getElementsByTagName('*')
for child in etiquetas:
    if child.tagName == "Covol:PRODUCTO":
        continue
    elif child.tagName != "Covol:REPORTEDEVOLUMENMENSUAL":
        if (node := child.firstChild) is not None and node.nodeType == child.TEXT_NODE:
            print(f"{child.tagName}: {node.data}")
        else:
            print(f"{child.tagName}: No tiene contenido")  
    else:
        break


Covol:ClaveProducto: PR07
Covol:ClaveSubProducto: SP16
Covol:Gasolina: No tiene contenido
Covol:ComposOctanajeGasolina: 87
Covol:GasolinaConCombustibleNoFosil: No
Covol:MarcaComercial: MAGNA SIN


También podrías simplemente manejar la excepción, o usar getattr():
    if data := getattr(child.firstChild, "data", None):
        print(f"{child.tagName}: {data}")


Muchísimas gracias FJSevilla por tu apoyo. Efectivamente, con la sentencia node := child.firstChild) is not None and node.nodeType == child.TEXT_NODE se subsanó el problema y ya pude concluir con el desdoble del archivo XML que estoy realizando. Nuevamente, muchas gracias.
